# Find the next div with the same class as the clicked div

Tags: jquery

How can I find the next `<div>` with the same class as the current one.

I have a `<div>` with `class="help"`, now when some clicks on a button inside  this `<div>` I want to select the next `<div>` with the same "help" class.

```
<div class="help">  
     <div>....OTHER HTML CONTENT......<div>
     <input type='submit' class='ok'>
</div>
<div>....OTHER HTML CONTENT......<div>
<div class="help"></div>
<div>....OTHER HTML CONTENT......<div>
<div>....OTHER HTML CONTENT......<div>
<div>....OTHER HTML CONTENT......<div>
<div class="help"></div>
<div>....OTHER HTML CONTENT......<div>
<div class="help"></div>
```

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a combination of [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

e.g.:

```
$("div.help").click(function() {
    var nextDiv = $(this).nextAll("div.help:first")
});
```

[`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) will only search the immediate sibling.

```
<div></div> <-- if you are here
<div></div> <-- .next() will check this
<div></div> <-- but nothing further on
```

You can of course, use a combination of `next()` and a loop, e.g.

```
// pseudo-code
while element is not div.help, element = element.next()
```

**EDIT**

`next()` and `nextAll()` will only search siblings -- ie elements on the same level. For example:

```
<div> <-- calling nextAll() from here will search:
    <div></div> x not this
</div>
<div> <-- this
    <div></div> x not this
</div>
<div></div> <-- this
```

So to get it to work with a multi-level layout, you need to first use some combination of [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/), which allow you to navigate one or more levels 'upwards'.

`parent()` will traverse one level up:

```
<div> <-- this is the parent()
    <div></div> <-- of this element
</div>
```

So in your particular example, starting from the button, you want to traverse one level up so you are on the same level as the other `<div class='help'>`, then use `nextAll()` to find the next div.

```
<div class="help">  // $(this).parent()
    <div>....OTHER HTML CONTENT......<div>
    <input type='submit' class='ok'> // $(this) is your starting point
</div>
<div>....OTHER HTML CONTENT......<div>
<div class="help"></div> // $(this).parent().nextAll("div.help:first")
```

Assuming of course, you are handling the click event of the input:

```
$("input.ok").click(function() {
    $(this); // in this scope the $(this) refers to the submit button
})
```

Answer (score 3):

[.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) - Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

Example :

```
<ul>
   <li>list item 1</li>
   <li>list item 2</li>
   <li class="third-item">list item 3</li>
   <li>list item 4</li>
   <li>list item 5</li>
</ul>


$('li.third-item').next().css('background-color', 'red');
```

**EDIT:**

[.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) : Get all following siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

So that in your case

```
$('div.help').nextAll(''div.help:first).css('background-color', 'red');
```

Comment: This only works for elements if they are directly next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/vV9C5/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".help").click(getNextHelp);
});

function getNextHelp() {
    var nextHelp = $(this).nextAll("div.help:first");
    if(nextHelp.length) {
        alert(nextHelp.html());
    } else {
        alert("that's the last help");
    }
}
```

**As per your EDIT and new request -**

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/vV9C5/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".help :button").click(getNextHelp);
});

function getNextHelp() {
    var nextHelp = $(this).parent().nextAll("div.help:first");
    if (nextHelp.length) {
        nextHelp.css("background", "red");
    } else {
        alert("that's the last help");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Web Developer - check now and try to post the correct question in one go. People might not come back to help you again.

Answer (score 0):

well, provide some basic scripts, the classic handler of cls made by Andrew Hayway && Simon Willison

```
function cls(c,tag){
    var r=[];
    var reg=new RegExp("(^|\s)"+c+"($|\s)");
    var e=document.getElementsByTagName(tag||"*");
    for(var i=0;i<e.length;i++){
        if(e[i].className.match(reg))
        r.push(e[i]);
    }
    return r;
}
var helps=cls('help','div');
for(var i=0;i<helps.length;i++){
    helps[i].onclick=function(){
        var next_index=helps.indexOf(this)+1;
        if(helps[next_index]){
            //here is the next dom with the class help
            var next=helps[next_index];
            //then your code...
        }
    }
}
```